# Returning a dragged applet to the browser window with Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, applet, draggable, japplet

I'm hoping to close the popped out applet to return it to the browser window where it was dragged out of. I'm doing this so that when the user moves from the applet's page, the applet doesn't remain open to them.

I've tried the `destroy()` method, the `stop()` method, as well as trying to call `removeAll()` on the container of the window, though I'm not sure I did that correctly.

Here's part of my code that gets called when the user wants to cancel the applet's execution. Instead of closing the applet, however, I just have it so the applet becomes invisible, though that leaves a big, blank window where the dragged out applet used to be and it's left to the user to close that.

```
function Cancel(){
    document.appletName.cancel();
    document.appletName.setVisible(false);
    window.location="/*newURL*/";
}
```

I want that window to close on its own, but I'm not sure what to call.

I don't have access to the source code of the applet, unfortunately, so this has to be done from the browser.

Comment: 1) I believe that applets dragged from the page no longer can interact with JS.  2) It might be best to avoid allowing applet drag in the first place. 3) *"I don't have access to the source code of the applet"*  Extend it. 4) There is no method for an applet to programatically close itself after being dragged from the page, but with a bit of hacking to discover the top-level window, it might be doable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

1)They can interact with the page still, but they don't close with the page like normal.

2)Unfortunately, it's impossible to prevent the user from dragging it in OSX. Since Apple decided it would be a good idea to prevent drag and drop usability in java applets, they also put in a workaround where you can hit command key + shift and drag the applet out of the window, regardless of the draggable parameter being set to true.

3)I'm not well versed in Java to know how to do that.

Comment: 4)I'm starting to realize that and I'm working towards making it so that the applet is unusable after they leave the page they dragged the applet from. Finding the top level window is also a good deal out of my league

Thanks for your response though. Good to know I'm not just shouting into the wind here. :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is no way to do this in a "zen" sort of way, but having the applet output some sort of informative message that it needs to be closed as well as using `setEnable(false)` to make it so they can't interact with it forces the user to have to close the applet. Not the most user friendly, but definitely a good way to go if you have users that will insist on dragging the applet out of their window.